# Retrieve cookie value using owa_cookie.get

Tags: cookies, oracle-apex

Using oracle apex version 22.2.0, i'm trying to set a cookie on my user's devices upon successful login. The next time they have to log in, they can bypass the MFA pages if their cookie still exists. To do this I have the login process and branch to homepage set with a SSC pl/sql function body:

```
DECLARE

    l_cookie owa_cookie.cookie;
    v_cookie_value  varchar2(50);
    v_count  number;
    v_result boolean;

BEGIN

    l_cookie := owa_cookie.get('LGN_C');
    v_cookie_value := l_cookie.vals(1);
    --:P9999_COOKIE_TARGET := l_cookie.vals(1);

    select count(*) into v_count from sandro.portal_logins where upper(username) = upper(:P9999_USERNAME) and mfastatus = 0;
    
    IF v_cookie_value IS NOT NULL THEN
        v_result := true;
    ELSIF v_count = 1 THEN
        v_result := true;
    else
        v_result := false;
    END IF;
    
   return v_result;

END;
```

If the function body returns true, the page will run the login process and re-direct the user to the homepage.

But every time I try to log in, I get a no data found error while processing the condition. I've removed just about every piece of the code and the error seems to be coming directly from 'l_cookie := owa_cookie.get('LGN_C');'. But in my screen shot, the cookie exists and does carry a value with it. Where am I going wrong here?[image: cookie error]

UPDATE 06/27/2023: I moved my owa_cookie.get function into a before header process and returned the value into a page item. This works perfectly as I can now use that page item in my SSC to determine which branches/processes to run. I'm assuming the error is part of my fundamental misunderstanding of cookies and how they work? Why can't I retrieve my cookie inside of a server side condition that runs after submit?